# SQLite.SQLiteException <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin. In the connection to my mainActivity I want to throw an Exception, but my Exception is getting an Exception that says

" SQLite.SQLiteException  "

I would provide code, but I'm not sure how much/which section would be needed.

Comment: Have you checked the ex.InnerException

Comment: Like Pedro says, are you able to check out the InnerException of said exception?